# Heroku push rejected

Tags: heroku, sinatra, bundler

```
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
^[[C^[[D^[[D/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../../tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile /tmp/build_22uiq5k0q45sp /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=900.1076555252075 (Utils::TimeoutError)
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `loop'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `block in spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `popen'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:37:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `fork'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:497:in `block in run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:496:in `run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `rescue in timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:97:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:114:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:113:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in '
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `block in lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `'
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rack app
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'sinatra', '1.3.3'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', '1.3.2'
gem 'thin', '1.5.0'
gem 'haml', '3.1.6'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'mongo', '1.8.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '1.8.0'
gem 'mongoid', '3.0.16'
gem 'sinatra-flash', '0.3.0'
gem 'braintree', '2.22.0'
gem 'faye', '0.8.6'
#gem 'pony'
```

The error is gone when I change

```
gem 'braintree', '2.22.0'
```

to

```
gem 'braintree'
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar failure in a python app that I'm trying to deploy. If yours is fixed like so, I'm going to try and play with my dependencies.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 do report about your findings. The problem with bundler is that sometimes it takes forever to figure out the dependencies, and in my case the culprit is the braintree gem and I think the fact that it requires a version of active-support different from mongoid.

Comment: Will do. Have to run some errands now though.

Comment: Nope. This didn't fix it.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 let's hope someone from heroku comes and clarifies!

Comment: I have a support ticket filed with them.

Comment: i'm getting this error as well. @sigmavirus24, how did your support ticket go?

Comment: I was told there shouldn't be a problem with the slug compiler in spite of it being demonstrably the compiler's issue and the issue was closed. It was clear I wasn't going to get anywhere with the ticket.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Looks like there's a fix now (see answer), though support may not have been aware of it when you asked them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This answer doesn't work. The only option is to raise a support ticket.

There's a new feature that fixes this problem:

```
$ heroku config:set COMPILE_TIMEOUT=n
```

where n is a number in seconds.  I used n=3000 (default is 900).

(note: you may need [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) enabled to use this feature)

**Update:** Please read the comments on this answer for updated information!

Comment: Hi, I work on Heroku's `git push heroku master` feature. This is incorrect. `COMPILE_TIMEOUT` does not control the build timeout. The timeout is 15 minutes. If your build consistently times out, please log a support ticket.

Comment: @NaamanNewbold Thanks for your comment! I have also given this answer to other questions and will amend them on those.  Do you have access to view Heroku ticket # 83810?  In this ticket, support staff said COMPILE_TIMEOUT was the solution to this problem.  I imagine they could have simply been mistaken, and my problem solved itself for unrelated reasons, but I wanted to see if you agree that the problem described in that ticket is the same as the problem in this question.

Comment: @NaamanNewbold Also, can you tell me what support staff will do in response to a ticket in the case of a build timing out, so I can have more context for this discussion?

Comment: Sure, we have an internal mechanism for extending timeouts and support will evaluate if it's a problem with the build, or you just need more time. We can't allow arbitrary timeouts for a number of reasons, service reliability being paramount. As for support's communication, there was probably a mixup with how this works internally. I ran a blame through our code base and didn't see an immediate reason why this ever worked (or if it even did work, it might've been a red herring). In any case, the way to do it now is through support. Let me know if you have any more questions. Thanks!

Comment: @NaamanNewbold Thanks, this is really helpful.  I appreciate you looking into it for me.  I'll edit this and other answers to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution that I found was:

- Push first half of my dependencies (half of the requirements.txt file)
- Push all the requirements.txt file (including opencv dependency), this work because heroku keep in cached the first half, so then the second installation will go more fast

Comment: How to push dependencies in two halves?

Comment: you have to delete some of the requirements of the requirements.txt and keep it in another file and then copy back again after you install the first half