# heroku push causes timeout error in slug-compiler for django

Tags: django, heroku, timeout

I have two heroku apps, staging and production.  I am able to push my latest code up to the staging server without issue, however when I try to push my latest code up to production I get a timeout error.

Looking at similar bugs that people have had it sounds like it could be an issue with the requirements doc or one of the packages. But I'm not sure how to even start debugging that.  We're using a lot of external packages.  And the fact that it works on one heroku app but not another makes me wonder how much it really is a previous app.

It appears to timeout at different times during the process without any other errors from what I can tell.  The first time it timed out after starting the install of psycopg2, however the last time it made it past psycopg2 and then timed out on the gevent install.

I'm at a loss and this is the first time I've ever encountered this problem and this build needs to go out asap.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is as much of the log as stackoverflow will allow me to post:

```
         Running setup.py install for django-extensions

         Running setup.py install for dj-database-url

         Running setup.py install for django-grappelli

         Running setup.py develop for ckeditor

           Creating /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django-ckeditor.egg-link (link to .)
           Adding django-ckeditor 3.6.2 to easy-install.pth file

           Installed /app/.heroku/src/ckeditor
         Running setup.py install for django-heroku-memcacheify

         Running setup.py install for django-tastypie

         Running setup.py install for boto
           package init file 'tests/db/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
           package init file 'tests/ec2/elb/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
           package init file 'tests/utils/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
           package init file 'boto/emr/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)

           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/sdbadmin from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/elbadmin from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cfadmin from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/s3put from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/fetch_file from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/launch_instance from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/list_instances from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/taskadmin from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/kill_instance from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/bundle_image from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pyami_sendmail from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/lss3 from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cq from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/route53 from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/s3multiput from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cwutil from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/instance_events from 600 to 755
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/asadmin from 600 to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/sdbadmin to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/taskadmin to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/lss3 to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/cq to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/route53 to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/cwutil to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/pyami_sendmail to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/instance_events to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/s3multiput to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/launch_instance to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/s3put to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/list_instances to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/bundle_image to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/kill_instance to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/elbadmin to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/fetch_file to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/cfadmin to 755
           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/asadmin to 755
         Running setup.py install for django-storages

         Running setup.py install for psycopg2
           building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/lib -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../../tmp/buildpacks/python/bin/compile /tmp/build_2ptirkdt1juhy /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=900.018394947052 (Utils::TimeoutError)
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `loop'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `block in spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `popen'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:37:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `fork'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:497:in `block in run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:496:in `run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `rescue in timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:97:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:114:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:113:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `block in lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>'
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
Connection to 10.217.65.204 closed by remote host.
To git@heroku.com:belo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:belo.git'
Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218704/heroku-push-rejected#comment19772321_14218704

Comment: It's similar, but since it's with python/django instead of ruby, and since it's a timeout error, it could potentially be an unrelated issue.  We've been pushing code updates to this app for over a year without encountering this issue.  Also, since I am able to push the identical code to our staging heroku app without any problem, I don't know if it's same cause.

Comment: Just to add a bit more information, it's not throwing the timeout error at the same place each time, as originally thought.  The last time I attempted it, it successfully ran the psycopg2 installation but then timed out in the middle of the gevent install.

Comment: If you look at the comments, I'm having the same problem with a Flask app, except in mine it times out at the same place every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's now a proper but undocumented solution to this problem (github history shows it was implemented in Feb. 2013): the `COMPILE_TIMEOUT` environment variable.  Set it like so for a 50 minute timeout (the default is '900', or 15 minutes):

```
$ heroku config:set COMPILE_TIMEOUT=3000
```

(note: you need [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) enabled to use this feature)

**Update:** Please read the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283513/471671) for an important update -- long story short, Heroku recommends contacting support directly in these cases, and COMPILE_TIMEOUT either no longer works or never worked as a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: The value is in seconds, right? You mentioned a "five-minute timeout", but wouldn't 3000 would be a "fifty-minute timeout"?

Comment: @jeremywoertink Whoops!  You are right.  I will edit the answer.  The number is sent through Ruby's `Timeout.timeout()` so it's definitely in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I heard back from Heroku support.  In my particular circumstance, the issue was that we simply have too many dependencies in requirements.  It is a very large scale project and we utilize many third party modules and it simply was taking too long to install and create the slug.

The solution was to comment out half of our requirements and push, then undo the comments and push again.

Here is the response from Heroku:

> That's a lot of dependencies!
>
> I'd recommend pushing once with only half of your dependencies, then once again with all of them. Then you won't hit the timeout.
>
> Once they are installed, they are cached, so you shouldn't run into this again.

Comment: Wow what a not great solution. We have about 50 3rd party dependencies (plus their dependencies), and I'm running into this a lot. Most of the time it's not bad, but about 10 of our dependencies are github tags of our own forks of other libraries, and any time one of those changes we have to flush the cache by changing the Python runtime to get it to rebuild the whole thing. And that's when this comes up. I like Heroku for a lot of things, but stuff like this makes me go "wow really?"

Comment: @GregHinch There's now a fix; see my new answer on this question.