# How to handle heroku `Timed out compiling Python app` when installing numpy and pandas

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I'm looking for a propper way to install numpy and pandas from a `requirements.txt` file as a dependency for my heroku django app without getting `Timed out compiling Python app (15 minutes)`

I know that there are some custom buildpacks like this [conda-buildpack](https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack)  but I need it as a pip requirement because some other packages load it as additional dependency.

The solution I found to install numpy and pandas in two different commits leads to the problem that when I delete the heroku cache for some reason I have todo this two commits again.

So I want to ask how I can exceed the 15 minutes heroku compile time?
How you guys handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently having the same issue (trying to install numpy, pandas, and bokeh and hitting the 15 minute heroku compile time limit).

Check out the **comments** from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218704/heroku-push-rejected/16283513#16283513). (The actual answer does not work/help, as explained in the comments)

Short version is in order to increase this time limit, you need to submit a [Heroku Help Ticket](https://help.heroku.com/). Internally, they can increase the time limit. Issue is it takes a few business days for them to respond to the tickets.

If you (or anyone else) finds another way to fix this error, let me know!